# pygame.Rect around circle

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a pong game in pygame, but I can't figure out how to put a ball circle, which I can create with `pygame.draw.circle` into a `pygame.Rect` object so i can use the colliderect function to manipulate the ball's position.

For example, a rectangle, I can do something like this:

```
rect = pygame.Rect(255, 255, 100, 100) 
pygame.draw.rect(screen, yellow, rect)
```

When I change the `pygame.Rect` object position, the drawing primitives position also changes.

How can the same effect be achieved when I want to draw a circle, instead of a rectangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you're using a center position and a radius to draw the circle.  Just create a rect like this:

```
crect = pygame.Rect(center[0]-radius, center[1]-radius, \
                    radius*2, radius*2)
```

Then draw the circle like this:

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, yellow, crect.center, radius)
```

Comment: I can't believe i couldn't figure out something so simple .d 
Thank you very much for your help.